# vba - change the color of a cell based on defined values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a bit of code that changes the interior color of a cell if a condition is met. This condition is: if a value (date) of a given cell like today's date < 20 then the interior color of that cell is changed.

I want these changes to be applied to four cells to the right (4 columns). The sub only works for one cell. Any ideas what is wrong? Is there something wrong with the loop?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        For i = 2 To i = 6
            If Target.Offset(0, i).Value - Date < 20 Then
                Target.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = rgbRed
            Else: Target.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = rgbWhite
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you can accomplish this without vba via conditional formatting. otherwise the syntax is off. `For i = 2 to 6` will work.

Comment: I know, but I'm learning vba and want to train.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
For i = 2 To i = 6
```

Change it to

```
For i = 2 To 5
```

To **5** because you want to change only four cells, with the offset 2, 3, 4 & 5.

**Update**

If you want to stop the formatting if a cell value is empty, then exit from the loop when this condition is met:

```
 For i = 2 To 5
    If Trim(Target.Offset(0, i).Value) = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    ...
 Next i
```

Comment: It works now ! Thank you. One more thing. I want this to happen: If a target.value is nothing then all formating to the right is canceled and code is stopped - how to do that?